# Docker (compose v3) static ip, not bind to localhost - Mac

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, traefik

I'm using docker on my mac for web development and it works really great,
I'm using docker-compose with a traefik container to tunnel it to my dev-websites on a shared network between the traefik and nginx containers.

Only problem i have is that i have a conflict on port 80, i'm justing in on a different program on my mac.

It there a way to bind a docker container(the traefik container) to a static container and not to localhost?

This is my compose file

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    container_name: traefik
    # The official v2.0 Traefik docker image
    image: traefik:v2.4
    # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    command:
      # - "--api.insecure=true" # Don't do that in production
      # - "--providers.docker=true"
      # - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      # - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      # - "--entrypoints.web-secure.address=:443"
      # - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      # - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.to=websecure
      # - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.scheme=https
      # - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      # - --entrypoints.websecure.http.tls=true
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --entrypoints.websecure.http.tls=true
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.to=websecure
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.scheme=https
    ports:
      # The HTTP port
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro



networks:
  default:
    name: traefik_proxy
    external: false
```

Comment: Why not just bind to a different port on your machine?

Comment: Because for testing websites i use websitename.test. Chrome automatically works with 80-443. Otherwise i need to use a port number every time.. I'm using dnsmasq for local dns

Comment: How about including the existing service on port 80 in your traefik network?

Comment: the conflicting service is not using docker and cant change the port of that program

Comment: If everything else is working other than the port I think the best solution I can suggest is just include the port number in your browser while developing.

Answer (score 1):

This is totally possible. What you need to do is have an alias ip to your lo0 interfaces, ie

```
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 123.123.123.123
```

check:

```
ifconfig lo0 | grep "inet "
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
    inet 123.123.123.123 netmask 0xff000000
```

Then bind your other container to this address on port 80 and you will be able to use it for local tests.

bind it in run command with

```
-p a.b.c.d:port:port
```

or in the compose file with the same syntax:

```
a.b.c.d:port:port
```

check:

having two containers, bound to port 80:

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                               NAMES
64676a694bda   mendhak/http-https-echo   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes   123.123.123.123:80->80/tcp          boring_murdock
c1671e852698   nginx                     "/docker-entrypoint.…"   6 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp   focused_cerf
```

sending request to a first container:

```
curl 0.0.0.0      # or curl localhost

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

sending request to another container, also on port 80:

```
curl -s 123.123.123.123

{
  "path": "/",
  "headers": {
    "host": "123.123.123.123",
    "user-agent": "curl/7.64.1",
    "accept": "*/*"
  },
  "method": "GET",
  "body": "",
  "fresh": false,
  "hostname": "123.123.123.123",
  "ip": "::ffff:172.17.0.1",
  "ips": [],
  "protocol": "http",
  "query": {},
  "subdomains": [],
  "xhr": false,
  "os": {
    "hostname": "64676a694bda"
  },
  "connection": {}
}
```

When done, you can remove the alias with:

```
ifconfig lo0 -alias 123.123.123.123
```

Comment: This works!! Wow you won't believe how happy I'm. This works on linux and Mac? And is there a possibility to add this command to a compose(like a pre-hook)?

Comment: I am glad I could help. I never tried hooks, but the approach definitely should work with both mac and linux, yes. Word of caution though, when choosing ips for the alias - probably stick with rfc1918 (private ip ranges), and don't go bananas with public ips like I did in my example, not that it will necessarily break something, but there is a possibility to shadow a real public ip and next thing you know google.com doesn't open or something 

Comment: as for the hooks, if that's not possible, you can create your own wrapper - a shell script that first creates an interfaces or alias and then uses that interface's IP in the compose (with the help of an env variable for instance)

Comment: or is it possible to set an alias from a docker-container to the host machine? And does an alias survive a restart or is there a way the check if the allies still exists?

Comment: yes, it is possible to set an alias from a docker container, you would need to have this container started bound to the host network though, alias survives the restart if configured and one way to check would be to parse the output of a command like ifconfig. All of these are great candidates for new topics.